# Make lists of all possible paths out of lists with different coordinates to chose from

Tags: python, arrays

An example list looks like this:
`l = [[[0, 4], [0, 2]], [[1, 3], [1, 6], [1, 2]]]`

And i want to make a list of all possible paths out of that list which would look like this:

```
l_paths = [[[0, 4], [1, 3]], [[0, 4], [1, 6]], [[0, 4], [1, 2]],  [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 6]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]]]
```

In this example `[[0, 4], [1, 3]]` is one path and another path is `[[0, 4], [1, 6]]` and so on.
How do I do this for any list?

I did this:

```
for i in l:
    path_list[0].append(i[0])
print(path_list)
```

and got:
`[[[0, 4], [1, 3]]]`

I was able to get the first possible path, however I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I'm assuming those represent a graph. Look up "depth first search" (DFS) and "breadth first search" (BFS). You'll have to do this, as we're not a tutorial site or code writing service, but we can point you in the right direction sometimes. It's probably a better idea to traverse the paths and do what you need to do right then (don't try to store them in lists for later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Cartesian product of your sublists. You can get this using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*l))
[([0, 4], [1, 3]), ([0, 4], [1, 6]), ([0, 4], [1, 2]), ([0, 2], [1, 3]), ([0, 2], [1, 6]), ([0, 2], [1, 2])]
```